# Why does this javascript won't work?

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to ask about this voting box that was included in our website files. Cause there seemed to be a problem with this. Whenever I click the "Click here to vote". Nothing happens, I do not have any idea why since I am not into java codings. I'd like to include the codes of it so you guys can take a look at.

This is the voting box: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LV8S.png

So this is the code of where you are going to click it:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    odbc_exec($mssql, 'USE [ACCOUNT_DBF]');
    $votepoints = odbc_exec($mssql, 'SELECT votepoints FROM [ACCOUNT_TBL] WHERE account=\''.mssql_escape_string($_SESSION['user']).'\'');
    echo 'Current Vote Points: <b><span id="currvp">'.odbc_result($votepoints, 'votepoints').'</span></b><br/><br/>';
    echo '<span id="takeitem"></span>';
    echo '<a href="javascript:voteTab();"><b>Click here to vote!</b></a>';
} else {
    echo '<b>You must login before you can vote!</b>';
}
```

This is the voteTab(); function:

```
function voteTab() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php?a=vote',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'php',
    timeout: 1000,
    success: function(response){
      $(".boxcontent").html(response);
    }
});
```

This is the ajax:vote function:

```
if($_GET['a'] == 'vote') { // Vote Box
    odbc_exec($mssql, 'USE [ACCOUNT_DBF]');
    $userselect = odbc_exec($mssql, 'SELECT * FROM [ACCOUNT_TBL] WHERE account=\''.mssql_escape_string($_SESSION['user']).'\'');
    $user = odbc_fetch_array($userselect);

    $diff1 = diff($user['lastvote1']);
    $diff2 = diff($user['lastvote2']);
    $diff3 = diff($user['lastvote3']);
    $votedtoday = 0;
    if($diff1['hours'] < 12)
        $votedtoday = $votedtoday + 1;
    if($diff2['hours'] < 12)
        $votedtoday = $votedtoday + 1;
    if($diff3['hours'] < 12)
        $votedtoday = $votedtoday + 1;
    echo 'Username: <b>'.$user['account'].'</b><br/><br/>';
    echo 'Current Vote Points: <b><span id="vpoints">'.$user['votepoints'].'</span></b><br/><br/>';
    echo 'You can vote <b><span id="vtoday"> '.(3 - $votedtoday).' </span></b> more times today.<br/><br/>';
    if($diff1['hours'] >= 12 || $diff2['hours'] >= 12 || $diff3['hours'] >= 12) {
        if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {
            if($_GET['submit'] == 1) {
                if($diff1['hours'] >= 12) {
                    odbc_exec($mssql, 'UPDATE [ACCOUNT_TBL] SET votepoints=votepoints+\'1\', lastvote'.mssql_escape_string($_GET['submit']).'=\''.date('d.m.Y H:i:s').'\' WHERE account=\''.mssql_escape_string($_SESSION['user']).'\'');
                }
            } elseif($_GET['submit'] == 2) {
                if($diff2['hours'] >= 12) {
                    odbc_exec($mssql, 'UPDATE [ACCOUNT_TBL] SET votepoints=votepoints+\'1\', lastvote'.mssql_escape_string($_GET['submit']).'=\''.date('d.m.Y H:i:s').'\' WHERE account=\''.mssql_escape_string($_SESSION['user']).'\'');
                }
            } elseif($_GET['submit'] == 3) {
                if($diff3['hours'] >= 12) {
                    odbc_exec($mssql, 'UPDATE [ACCOUNT_TBL] SET votepoints=votepoints+\'1\', lastvote'.mssql_escape_string($_GET['submit']).'=\''.date('d.m.Y H:i:s').'\' WHERE account=\''.mssql_escape_string($_SESSION['user']).'\'');
                }
            }
        }
        echo 'You gain 1 Vote Point each topsite.<br/>After voting you will be able to choose a free gift!<br/>Follow the instructions to vote for all 3 topsites.<br/><br/><div id="topsite" style="text-align: center;">';
        if($diff1['hours'] >= 12) {
            // Top of Games
            echo '<img src="img/tog.gif" /><br/><br/>';
            echo '<span id="votetext"><a onclick="vote(1, '.$diff2['hours'].', \''.$votelist2.'\', \''.$votelist3.'\');" href="'.$votelist1.'" target="_blank">Click here to continue!</a></span>';
        } elseif($diff2['hours'] >= 12 ) {
            // Xtreme Top 100
            echo '<img src="img/xtop100.jpg" /><br/><br/>';
            echo '<span id="votetext"><a onclick="vote(2, '.$diff3['hours'].', \''.$votelist2.'\', \''.$votelist3.'\');" href="'.$votelist2.'" target="_blank">Click here to continue!</a></span>';
        } elseif($diff3['hours'] >= 12) {
            // G Top 100
            echo '<img src="img/gtop100.jpg" /><br/><br/>';
            echo '<span id="votetext"><a onclick="vote(3, 0, \''.$votelist2.'\', \''.$votelist3.'\');" href="'.$votelist3.'" target="_blank">Click here to continue!</a></span>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="javascript:voteItemTab();">Choose an item!</a>';
    }
}
/* VOTE BOX END */
```

I really need some answers of how it will work.

Comment: Does the ajax fire? Is there an error in the console?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I do not know what you mean by "ajax fire". Cause I am not really into codings.

Comment: Fire, as in execute. Open the network console in the developer tools of your browser and click the button. Does it send out and return? What is the response?

Comment: Do you mean this? Uh, I do not know how to know if it sends out and returns something. http://i.imgur.com/K4yfCU4.png

Comment: Yes, so that looks like it isnt sending. This could be because of a JS error (the red circle with the 'x' in the image indicates some sort of error. Could you click the console tab and see what that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing curl brace on your function.

```
function voteTab() {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'ajax.php?a=vote',
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'php',
       timeout: 1000,
       success: function(response){
        $(".boxcontent").html(response);
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There probably problem with your PHP code that handle, database connection. Much better if you try to put error catch/break (on each line that handle db)
and check the  **error.log** to see what might break in background.

I've also notice some security flaw when you do AJAX request, MITM attack can change the response coming to your PHP code, try also to sanitize request and response.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. But there is no problem with the database connection.

Comment: @jovenb Could you elaborate on the MITM attack vector you're mentioning? I can't see anything wrong with the request, as far as i can see the request data is only used to branch to the appropriate action.

Comment: Hi @Fur, I recommend you to use Fiddler/Devtools to see whats happening to your AJAX request.. There really might some problem with your request or responses, that's why it wont return any results.

Comment: and also dont know what you mean on this dataType: 'php', try to remove this.

Comment: Hi, so I have tried removing the "dataType: 'php'," but it doesn't seemed to fix the problem. Thank you so much having such effort of helping me fix this out.